# How to convert vector<vector<int>> to array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, int

I am wondering whether there is a smarter approach to convert a `std::vector<std::vector<int>` to an array, given each vector item is of fixed size:

I am currently using:

```
  unsigned int cell_size = pCells[0].size();
  std::vector<int> kCells(pCells.size()*cell_size);
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<pCells.size(); i++){
     for (unsigned int j=0; j< cell_size; j++){
    kCells[i*cell_size+j] = pCells[i][j];
     }
  }
  // array
  int* lCells = &kCells[0];
```

Comment: At least you may use `std::copy` instead of the nested loop

Comment: Isn't this question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @mvidelgauz Probably not. Code Review expects complete, [theoretically] production level code that can be reviewed, this code snippet is nowhere near complete enough for their standards.

Comment: Is that a real code or just an example? Because `lCells` is here a dangling pointer

Comment: @Xirema Thank you for clarification. I am still far from good understanding those [possible directions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: man, please don't be pedantic. It's a simple question I am raising here, please be constructive :)

Comment: @Nabil.G I am fully with you! But I am afraid that here your question will soon be closed by mods as off-topic. I would like to be wrong...

Comment: @Nabil.G  The code you showed creates a new vector. It does not create an array. The memory belongs to the vector and depends on the life-time of the vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The content of a vector is an array.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is who is the owner of the memory.

Comment: @Vlad: An array can be owned, too.  Would you be happier if the code used `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `vector<int>`?  Both are arrays stored in a smart pointer, the only real difference is that the vector knows its size and can change it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I do not see a sense. Either you are creating a vector or you are creating an array.

Comment: @BenVoigt And the difference is not in the size. The difference is the life-time.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Creating a vector *does* create an array.  The vector points to the array.

Comment: @Nabil.G does this array need to own its contents or are you okay with just pointing to the buffer of a vector and doing manual safety checks?

Comment: @BenVoigt As I said it is an incorrect point of view because the question arises who is the owner of the memory. For example the vector can leave the scope of the array and the memory will be deleted. It is an invalid approach and does not create an array.

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Because `kCells` and `lCells` are in the same scope, `kCells` will be destroyed after `lCells` and there is no dangling pointer.  If this isn't the real code and the pointer is copied to a larger scope, then yes there could be a problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: So is your complaint actually "`lCells` is a non-owning pointer"?  Because that has nothing at all to do with vector-vs-array.

Comment: @NathanOliver: no it does not need to own its contents.

Comment: @BenVoigt How do you know `kCells` will remain "valid" until `lCells` is destroyed? Any call in the same scope on `kCells` leading to a reallocation of the vector will be UB. As @VladfromMoscow tries to explain you, the address of a static array and a dynamic array aren't the same things

Comment: @BenVoigt You are mistaken. It has direct relation to a creating an object. Here lCells is an alias for another object that is of its part. It is not a stand-alone object.

Comment: @BenVoigt Each object is defined by its memory and by its own life-time.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Every non-null pointer is a handle aliasing another object (The pointer is itself an object too).  So are you actually complaining that `lCells` is a pointer not a statically-dimensioned array (size fixed at compile time)?

Comment: @BenVoigt There is not even created a dynamically allocated array. There is created a vector. This vector has its own memory and its own life-time.

Comment: @wasthishelpful: It's true that the address of a static array has type `int (*)[N]` and the address of a dynamic array has type `int*`.  But no one uses the address-of operator on a static array, they just let its name decay to a pointer.  But what was your point?  Static, dynamic, and automatic objects certainly all have different lifetime, but use-after-free has little to do with array-vs-vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Of course there is a dynamically allocated array created.  Just like `make_unique` dynamically allocates an object.  You're just using a helper to do the allocation instead of saying `new` yourself.

Comment: @Nabil.G Why `lCells`? What's wrong with using `kCells`?

Comment: @Hurkyl how would you implement it? I did not manage to get it work.

Comment: @Nabil.G That's not evident from your question. What doesn't work? What did you expect the code to do and what did it actually do?

Comment: pretty interesting to get a downvoted question. I have the strong feeling that one needs to be rather careful before raising a question on Stackoverflow. I aimed to have some answer and not generate some endless discussion between "self pro-claimed" experts. Anyhow, the approach I posted does the job. In addition, many thanks to @NathanOliver who  was tried to give a solution.

Comment: @BenVoigt This statement int* lCells = &kCells[0]; creates nothing. The code snippet creates a vector. There is created neither array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: A vector is a helper object for creating and managing an array.  You can get direct access to that array via `vector::data()`, you don't have to use vector iterators to access it.

Comment: @BenVoigt One more this statement int* lCells = &kCells[0]; creates nothing. There is no conversion from a vector to an array in the code snippet. There is conversion from one vector to another vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Of course that statement does create a pointer, and does not create an array.  We agree on that.  But the code most certainly does convert from a vector of vectors to an array.  The array is created by `std::vector<int> kCells(pCells.size()*cell_size);` (as a side effect of `std::vector::vector`, this is not a declaration of an array).  `int* lCells = &kCells[0];` is not creating that array, it is accessing it.

Comment: @BenVoigt The array does not exist without the vector and moreover can stop ito exist then an element will be added to the vector. It is the same as to say for this code int *p; { int a[N]; p = a; } // where is the array? that we created an array. No we created nothing except the pointer itself..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: In that snippet you created and destroyed an array.  You have proven yourself that while lifetime may be a concern, the lifetime concern is not caused by using a helper class (whether `std::vector<int>` or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`) for the array.  In fact, the helper class is designed to help solve the lifetime problem.  Notice the big difference between your code and the one in the question -- in your code the pointer is declared first, in the question the pointer is declared after the array is created.  C++ destroys locals in the opposite order of creation...

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to get a `int*` from a 2d vector would be to use a temporary vector to build the buffer and then pointing to that buffer.  The down fall with this approach is that you have to make sure the pointer does not outlive the vector and that the vector is not modified in a way that would cause the pointer to become invalid(typically this is anything that would cause a reallocation or shifting of elements).  If you are okay with that then you can use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data; // we assume this is populated
std::vector<int> builder;
builder.reserve(data.size() * data[0].size()); // reserve space in builder. not needed but useful if you already now how many elements you need

for (const auto& row : data)
    builder.insert(builder.end(), row.begin(), row.end()

int * non_owning_ptr = &builder[0];
```

Now you have a non-owning pointer to the contents of builder and all the pitfalls that comes with.  The pitfalls can be avoided, except for possible invalidation due to modifying the vector, as long as `non_owning_ptr` does not leave the scope that `builder` is declared in.  You can pass it to a function in the same scope but you cannot pass it up and out of the current scope.

Another option is to use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` but you need to know the exactly how many elements you need as you cannot grow the `unique_ptr`.  This is better than using a raw pointer and `new` as you do not need to remember to call `delete` when you are done.  You still have the same scoping issues where you need to make sure the pointer does not outlive the `std::unique_ptr`.  You also have to make sure you do not do any operation on it that will delete the pointer like calling `reset`.  Using a `unique_ptr` you could use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data; // we assume this is populated
auto builder = std::make_unique<int[]>(data.size() * data[0].size());
int * end = builder.get(); // for std::copy

for(const auto& row : data)
{
    std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), end);
    end += row.size();
}

int * non_owning_ptr = builder.get();
```

The only other way to get an array would be to `new` up the pointer, copy the data into the new buffer and then `delete` it when you are done.  This still isn't the greatest since you have to remember to call `delete` when you are done with the buffer but at least the pointer "owns" the data and can be passed wherever.  You also have to make sure whatever you call does not call delete on the pointer otherwise you will have a double delete when you go to delete it.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data; // we assume this is populated
int * buffer = new int[data.size() * data[0].size()];
int * end = buffer; // for std::copy

for(const auto& row : data)
{
    std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), end);
    end += row.size();
}

// use buffer here

// don't forget this when done
delete [] buffer;
```

Comment: In the final alternative (manual call to `new[]` and `delete[]`) you still have the problem that some piece of code could call `delete[]` on a copy of your pointer, still killing the array).  So it has all the same potential problems as `vector<int>` or `unique_ptr<int[]>`, and none of the benefits.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is that but you also have that with every other solution so I didn't think it mattered.

Comment: I know you know that, but the way you wrote your answer, the two ways using smart pointers you listed the potential problems, and then the most fragile way you didn't mention any at all.  A skilled programmer is already familiar with the fragility of manual memory management, but many of SO's readers are not.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah.  I added some the caution about having a double delete.  I see where you are coming from now.

Answer (score 0):

C++ provides a lot of better options than what you're doing, listed from best to worst:

1. Construct your `vector<vector<int>>` as a `vector<int>`, doing 2D indexing into a 1D array where necessary, then don't even bother doing the conversion and directly use the `vector<int>`
2. Use `#define`s to establish size the height and width of the array, and use `array` rather than `vector` to store the elements
3. The worst case is what you've done, made more brutally bad by the fact you do: `int* lCells = &kCells[0]` meaning `lCells` is subject to invalidation by any change that would invalidate iterators to `kCells`

**1** requires changes on your part external to the code in the question so I won't demonstrate that. **2** can be done like this though, given: `#define WIDTH 3`, `#define HEIGHT 2`, and that your input is defined like: `array<WIDTH, array<HEIGHT, int>> pCells` you can do:

```
int lCells[WIDTH * HEIGHT];

for_each(begin(lCells), end(lCells), [i = cbegin(pCells), j = cbegin(pCells)->cbegin()](auto& it) mutable {
    if(j == i->cend()) j = (++i)->cbegin();

    it = *j++;
});
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/OTHfKk)

Comment: @Downvoter Could I get clarification on the downvote? If it's just the mandatory C++ downvote no need to respond.

Comment: So your solution is to not allow the size to be determined at runtime at all?  That's not solving any problem, it is making things worse.

Comment: @BenVoigt That was one of my proposed solutions, and if it's possible that'd be desirable. But the most desirable solution would be to use a `vector<int>` rather than a `vector<vector<int>>` using 2D indexing into the 1D array: http://upcoder.com/2/efficient-vectors-of-vectors